# Flaticons Show up all Black with CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

have been unable to resolve this. I downloaded icons and using the demo they all show up back when they should show up in a more colorful fashion

What they should look like: http://www.flaticon.com/packs/interaction-assets-2

How it looks like for me: http://chathelpdesk.com/pp-menu/demo/assets/fonts/flaticon.html

I see the outline of the icon, I am using the default CSS. The outline of the font icon is there. Could someone help figure out how to un-black the icons...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

CSS Icon fonts can't have multiple colors (Only one solid color). You will need to use an alternative such as SVG icons.

Comment: Thank you!  I have spent several hours trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across this issue myself.
You do seem to have something to do with fonts, but the page you've screenshotted that is black is the demo file the send with your download, so at the very least, that should work.

In my instance, I downloaded the SVG sprites version and got a demo file that looked the same - and when I imported the SVG's they were also black.

I noticed on the flaticon website it allows you to "paint" a collection before downloading - which just applied a solid colour to all objects. I think this is what is happening somehow. When I look at the svg code, it lists the fill's as "null".

I've since downloaded the same icons individually and it worked fine. So I think there is something wrong with their collection download ability.